# Calculate overtime from datetime

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to calculate overtime based on a overtimefactor of 07:24:00:0000 hours

My database looks like this

```
| id  |user_id|     starttime       | endtime
|  0  |   1   | 2018-05-09 04:30:00 | 2018-05-09 017:30:00
|  1  |   1   | 2018-05-10 06:30:00 | 2018-05-10 017:30:00
|  2  |   1   | 2018-05-11 04:30:00 | 2018-05-11 015:30:00
```

I am having a hard time figuring out the selectstatement that would do the job - I want ALL combined overtime as a result

My function i have now looks like this:

```
public function getOvertimeTotal($id, $selectedMonth) {
      $this->db->query("SELECT 
      COUNT(SUBTIME(TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, starttime, endtime), '07:24:00:0000')) as overTimeTotal
      FROM hours
      WHERE user_id = :id
      AND month(starttid) = :selectedMonth");

      $this->db->bind(':id', $id);
      $this->db->bind(':selectedMonth', $selectedMonth);

      $row = $this->db->single();

      return $row;

    }
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Why the `COUNT()` ??

Comment: Instead of COUNT() you should use SUM(), if you want to sum the overtime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should help you calculate overtime in fractional hours,

```
SUM((TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, starttime, endtime) - TIME_TO_SEC('07:24:00:0000')) / 3600)
```

[SQLFiddle link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d72dc0/1)

---

If you need the value converted back in time remove division by 3600 part from above and use `SEC_TO_TIME()` function

```
SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, starttime, endtime) - TIME_TO_SEC('07:24:00:0000')))
```

Comment: So with the help of you guys i now have this:  

SELECT 
      SUM(overtime) AS overTimeTotal 
      FROM (
        SELECT SUM((TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, starttid, sluttid) - TIME_TO_SEC('07:24:00:0000')) / 3600) AS overtime
        FROM hours
        WHERE user_id = :id
        AND month(starttid) = :selectedMonth) AS T
      ");  

But this return 6.2000 - but should return 6:12 as in 12 minutes  

Im glad for your help, much appreciated.

Comment: It returns fractional hours. Converting fractional hours to hours:minutes should give you the correct answer.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out here. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try to compute the overtime in a subquery and then aggregate over the named result column:

```
SELECT SUM(overtime) AS overTimeTotal 
FROM (SELECT starttime - endtime AS overtime FROM tablename WHERE [...])
```

I am leaving out the `WHERE` part for simplicity.